# robot initial localization

Tags: localization, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, every one, I have build a map with Pioneer robot P3AT now, and the navigation node alse seems run well. But there is one question:
***How to initial localize the robot in the map?***

That is to say, the problem of "global localization", after we fire up the navigation node, we have to localize robot in map accoring to the laser reading, this is not a problem while running with stage, because we can always set the position of robot in *.world and *.yaml exactly same. But, if run with a real robot, it's almost impossible to put the robot at an exactly correct position according to what we have set in *.yaml.

In the toolbar of rviz, there have a button says "2D Pose Estimate", but I don't think it's what I'm finding, because it's just put robot at the position where mouse click, I guess it's just initialize the particle filter used in amcl, but not sure for this.

Dose anyone have suggestion for this?  Or is there exist a implemented answer for this in ROS ?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38985/robot-initial-localization/) by [viking](https://answers.ros.org/users/2532/viking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2018-06-18**:
Do you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To test the global_localization in amcl suggest by Stephan, I have launch a navigation task work with stage, which was configured according to [navigation node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup), and just modify the map to one built by myself. After start up, the laser scan and obstacle in rviz fixed very well. But, once I run global_localization by type:

```
rosservice call /global_localization
```

I can see blow output in terminator which roslaungh run:

```
[ INFO] [1342528758.779217076, 70.900000000]: Initializing with uniform distribution
[ INFO] [1342528758.808788272, 70.900000000]: Global initialisation done!
```

But the position of robot have change very much, and the laser scan doesn't fix with obstacle any more!

Is there something I have missed?  Dose global_localization works well on your side?

(Because the karma is too low, I can't upload the screenshot of ros running now, sorry for this >_< )

---

Originally posted by [viking](https://answers.ros.org/users/2532/viking/) with karma: 46 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2